# AC to DC power supply using full wave rectifier with 4 outputs

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, full-bridge

[image]I simulated the circuit below with multisim and got the required values.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

1.25 to 22V using the poistive regulator 
-1.25V TO -22V using the negative regulator 
+5V using 7805 
-5V using 7905

But when i built the circuit on the bredboard i dont get close to these vakues except the +5V using 7805. The inductor gets very hot and the transformer starts stinking up. Transformer secondary voltage is around 17Vrms.

Comment: Your circuit is shrouded by text boxes and there is no sign of a transformer. Also, there are wire connection dots that don't seem to connect to wires and wires that cross other wires then connect to them - badly drawn circuits are harder to read so please fix it up.

Comment: The schematic looks to be completely messed up at bridge D5.  First: the AC source is best done as a center-tapped transformer.  You can get away not using a center-tap to get your negative rails but that calls for more space than this comment allows.  So start off by deleting all of the negative-voltage stuff.  Next: move your ground connection from the bottom AC terminal on D5 to the (-) terminal instead.  That should get your positive voltage stuff working.  We can help you with the negative voltage stuff later.

Comment: And C8 and C10 are missing their ground connections.

Answer (score 1):

If the transformer stinks this means its temperature is way too high, which means it is delivering way too much current. I assume you haven't connected any loads to your power supply, so it should only draw the idle currents for the regulators, which are a couple tens mA at worst.

Check your wiring for a short somewhere.

Check polarized capacitors are connected with the proper polarity.

Remove voltage regulators and check with continuity tester in diode mode. You should measure a diode threshold or more between each pin. If two pins are shorted together, there's a problem.

Divide and conquer: if the problem persists with voltage regulators removed, then the problem is upstream of the regulators. Then put them back one at a time, and find which one is trouble, then look downstream.